# How to check the mandatory field with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a asp.net web page where my requirement was to show loading image until the gridview loads data after clicking the Submit button. So, I have researched on the internet and managed to this as per below code:

```
        function ShowProgress() {
        myVar = setTimeout(function () {
            var modal = $('<div />');
            modal.addClass("modal");
            $('body').append(modal);
            var loading = $(".loading");
            loading.show();
            var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
            var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
            loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
        }, 200);
    }
    $('form').live("submit", function () {
        ShowProgress();
    });
```

But now the problem is : when user clicks on "Submit" button then it does not check for mandatory field and it keep on showing the loading symbol until or unless we refresh the page using "F5". I am using RequiredFieldValidator of asp to check for mandatory field and it works fine with the Submit button but only the loading modal does not consider those mandatory field. Please suggest me on this how I may achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note: [jQuery `live` is deprecated](https://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: are your using asp.net validation control or jquery validation?

Comment: what mandatory field? Code shown should submit a form using browser default process and reload a new page. Doesn't make sense that the loading modal continues to be displayed. Is there another submit handler for the form that you haven't shown?

Comment: @qamar I am using asp.net validation. For example: RequiredFieldValidator for textbox.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara thanks. But I am quite new in Jquery could you please provide me an example.

Comment: @charlietfl My form has mandatory three textbox (with RequiredFieldValidator) which need to be filled up before submit so the submit button checks for the validation but the loading modal does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your jquery click event put this condition with your **ValidationGroup** name . here  **val** is my **ValidationGroup** name

```
 $('form').live("submit", function () {
if (Page_ClientValidate('val') == true)
{
        ShowProgress();
}
    });
```